# Identity vs CA Certs in mutual TLS server

Tags: ssl, iis, tomcat, tls

Dealing with a customer having trouble configuring mutual TLS (client certificates). In my experience, TLS client authentication works by the server having a cert, and telling the client to send a cert signed by that first cert. The client sends one (signs something with it), and the server  verifies that.

The customer is trying to use a CA cert in the server's trust store. In their case, anybody can request a cert from that CA. So, this will not work with the above - since anyone could get an identity cert from the CA and connect.

This behavior appears to be the Java default. In the past this is the approach I'd take - to use an intermediate cert or otherwise a CA that can be controlled.

I know a custom Java TrustManager can be implemented on the client to send any cert, regardless of its origin. I also know curl will do this (ignoring the cert authority in the CertificateRequest). With this approach you can use the identity cert, and not the CA, so the client and server can use the same certificate, regardless of its origin.

What is the best practice here? Is the customer making a reasonable request? We also have a Windows server to configure next and I don't know how it will handle this behavior.

**Edit:** The RFC does appear to make this behavior optional.

> certificate_authorities: A list of the distinguished names [X501] of acceptable
> certificate_authorities, represented in DER-encoded format.  These
> distinguished names may specify a desired distinguished name for a
> root CA or for a subordinate CA; thus, this message can be used to
> describe known roots as well as a desired authorization space.  If
> the certificate_authorities list is empty, then the client MAY
> send any certificate of the appropriate ClientCertificateType,
> unless there is some external arrangement to the contrary.
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.4

Comment: It is `KeyManager` in a Java client not `TrustManager` that controls the cert and key to use to authenticate i.e. the first not second argument to `SSLContext.init()`. OpenSSL's standard logic (without callback) is to use the cert&key specified on the commandline regardless of the server's 'desired' list, and thus so does `curl` it if uses OpenSSL, but `curl` can use several other SSL/TLS libraries also and I don't know if it's the same there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical reason why the CA used for the server certificate needs to be the same CA used by the client certificates.

There might be some reason why you desire, and require through configuration, that for a specific environment, but it isn't technically required.

The client defines the CAs that are trusted by the client (or they use the certifcate store from the operating-system/browser).  The server can usually do the same.  Use all the CAs trusted by the OS, or trust specific CAs.

If you need to require that that all the client certs be signed by a specific CA, you can certainly do that.

The specifics of how you set the CAs trusted by your server completely depend on your server software, which you didn't really mention other then 'Windows'.

> In their case, anybody can request a cert from that CA. So, this will not work with the above - since anyone could get an identity cert from the CA and connect.

This will depend on the server software you use, and if you trust the CA.  But with some servers you can set constraints based on the details included in the client certificate.  For example, you could require that users get a cert from a certain CA, and also require that the cert include an email in the subject that matches `@example.org`. If the CA is doing their job properly they will have validated that the details included in the certificate are in fact true as part of the signature.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - the normal server "SSL" cert is indeed different. I'm talking about the cert in the server's truststore above.